# Capture the end of the link using php

Tags: php, web, hyperlink

I am making a PHP based website, where I need to capture the end of the link which is actually a username and wanna use it for generating the profile of that user.

the link structure is as follows

**www.mywebsite.com/profile/username**

I want to capture the username (the end of the above link).

Is there any easy way to do it ?

Comment: @Ancient Geek Capturing the link was hard, not exploding it. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all before asking a question, always provide the code you already tried, because people help each other fixing the code, not creating the code for them from scratch,

Anyway, following is the solution for your problem,

```
$link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$end_of_link = basename($link);
```

Comment: Yes, this worked for me and also it looks cleaner. Thank You.

Comment: If you're sure about what you said than please Accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [ltrim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) it will get job done easily

Comment: Yes, its also a good option, thank you.